# cmake_find_package and cmake INTERFACE packages

Tags: conan

I have a CMake project (let's call it A) that uses the [interface libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/add_library.html#id6) feature of CMake and a CMake project using that interface (B). Now I'm trying to create conan recipes (it is working without problems with pure CMake).

As I did not want to modify my CMakeLists.txt to keep package management separated from the build process, I thought that the [cmake_find_package generator](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/build_system/cmake/cmake_find_package_generator.html) would be the way to go, but the resulting Find*Package*.cmake file for package A results in B trying to link against an non-existing (because pure interface) library.

I have a workaround (using the normal CMake generator as my CMakeLists.txt creates correct *Package*Config.cmake files which are found by find_package() also when building with conan), but as that workaround requires me to include the conanbuildinfo.cmake and call conan_basic_setup(), I wanted to ask:

Is conan's cmake_find_package generator working with interface libraries and if, how do I configure it correctly?

Comment: Hi @Blutkoete. It is possible that the ``cmake_find_package`` generator has some issue, maybe this deserves  an issue in https://github.com/conan-io/conan

Comment: I created an issue, thank you. https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/6785